# git commit opens up two editor panes instead of one to enter message

Tags: git, commit, vi

When i run `git commit` it opens up 2 vi editor panes instead of one. The top pane is totally blank. The bottom pane is what I expect to see when running `git commit`. Every time I want to commit I have to close the top pane using `:q` before I can write my commit message.

Has anyone seen something like this before? What is the solution?

Comment: If you close first the other panel (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/4810928/6309), would the issue persist at the next commit message?

Comment: What is the output of: `git config --global core.editor`  and `echo $GIT_EDITOR`

Comment: @VonC - I always have to close the other panel. I am unable to move my cursor to the panel where I would write the commit message unless I close the other panel first.

Comment: @Mondkin - both commands result in nothing. I did `git config --global core.editor vi` and also did `export GIT_EDITOR=vi` but that did not help my problem.

Comment: Then, what do you have in your `.vimrc` ?

Comment: Try set EDITOR to vim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why this worked, but I commented out a line in my .vimrc that changed the colorscheme.
`colorscheme solarized`. Seems to have fixed the problem somehow. I guess the git commit wants to use a vi without customization and for some reason opens up a secondary pane when a different colorscheme is present.

---

UPDATE:

Fixed by putting the `colorscheme solarized` line in my .vimrc in an if block to see if it is called by `git commit`.

Changed .vimrc:

```
if $_ != 'git commit' 
colorscheme solarized 
endif
```

Comment: Nice feedback, +1. Not sure why the colorscheme matters though.

Comment: If anyone figures out the _why_ of this, *please* update!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is that Git doesn't know what editor you want to use, so it runs `vi` by default, which launches Vim in compatibility mode.

This could also happen with other applications, so you could set the `VISUAL` and/or `EDITOR` environment variables (or/as well as the git-specific `GIT_EDITOR`) in your `~/.bashrc` to fix this:

```
EDITOR=vim
VISUAL=vim
```

Alternatively, you can configure git itself to use vim:

`git config --global core.editor "vim"`